# Fullcalendar Scheduler Printing - repeat headings on each page

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I have a scheduler calendar with a lot of  resources, usually printing on ~8 pages. However, the dates are not repeating on the top of each page, which makes all the pages after the first one essentially useless to me. Is there a way to force the headers to repeat on each page?

I'm using fullcalendar scheduler v5.3.2 (so am using the adaptive plugin)

Comment: Personally I suspect not, because the browser is just printing the existing HTML. But you could raise an issue about it on the fullcalendar GitHub page and see if they think it's fixable (because the print-specific CSS and the calendar layout is internal fullCalendar code, it's not a usage issue we can help you with here.)